# How make condition the elements in two arrays, Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

How compare elements in different arrays or make how make block `if ()`?

if `string[] data = { "a", "b" };` that's array which have the info.

the `string[] b = { "a" };` - checking array.

I must to check have array `b` the element which have the `data` array.

if in `b` all element tha same like in `data` i do something....

if `string[] c = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };` - don't the same, because `data` don't have  "c" and "d"

I try to use `Intersect().Any()` in block `if` it doesn't work in case array `c` because `Any` find first rigth element

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. Be sure to include sample inputs in your [mcve] **as well as the results you expect** based on those sample inputs.

Comment: I expect you want `c.Except(data).Any()` (assuming `b` and `c` can't have duplicates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `!Except` + `Any`:

```
bool containsAll = !data.Except(yourArray).Any();
```

or probably less efficient with large arrays but maybe little bit more readable:

```
bool containsAll = data.All(yourArray.Contains);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is used only to do lookups, you can use a `HashSet` instead:

```
HashSet<string> data = new HashSet<string>() { "a", "b" };

if (b.All(data.Contains))
{
    // All the strings in b are in data
}
```

Otherwise you can use `Except` as suggested by @mjwills:

```
if (!b.Except(data).Any())
{
    // All the strings in b are in data
}
```